# Is ClassName.variable always a static member variable?

Tags: javascript, static, namespaces, es6-class

I had never seen syntax like below, where a variable is directly initialized by appending to the class name (except in case of static members)

```
class Fruit {
  constructor(color) {
    this.color = color;
  }
}
Fruit.count = 0;
```

Where does this `count` variable go in the memory? I can't access it with class instance. So, is it a static member implicitly. How will it look in Classical Prototypal Inheritance? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any property directly assigned to a class, like with `Fruit.count = 0;`, is considered to be a validly assigning **static** variable/member. One actually uses the [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) as namespace.

Examples ...

```js
class Fruit {
  constructor(color) {
    this.color = color;
  }
}
Fruit.count = 0;

console.log('considered to be "static" ... Fruit.count :', Fruit.count);

const fruitType = new Fruit('yellow');

console.log('fruitType.constructor.count :', fruitType.constructor.count);
```

```js
class Fruit {
  constructor(color) {
    this.color = color;
  }
  static count = 42;
}

console.log('literally "static" ... Fruit.count :', Fruit.count);

const fruitType = new Fruit('red');

console.log('fruitType.constructor.count :', fruitType.constructor.count);
```

```js
function Fruit(color) {
  this.color = color;
}
Fruit.count = 9;

console.log('old school "static" ... Fruit.count :', Fruit.count);

const fruitType = new Fruit('pink');

console.log('fruitType.constructor.count :', fruitType.constructor.count);
```

> *How will it look in Classical Prototypal Inheritance?*

*Static* and *Prototypal* do not have anything in common. Thus there will not be any valid answer to this last Q.

But in case the OP was referring with *"Classical Prototypal Inheritance"* to ES3 syntax then it has been answered by the third example code.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Fruit {
  constructor(color) {
    this.color = color;
  }
  static s = 1
}

Fruit.count = 0
const f = new Fruit('red')
```

`count` and `s` are a properties of `Fruit` object. `console.dir(Fruit)` results in -

```
class Fruit
  count: 0
  s: 1
  arguments: (...)
  caller: (...)
  length: 1
  name: "Fruit"
  prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
  __proto__: ƒ ()
  [[FunctionLocation]]: VM924:2
  [[Scopes]]: Scopes[2]
```

In the above output, `Fruit.prototype.constructor` and `Fruit` are same i.e. `Fruit.prototype.constructor === Fruit` is `true`.

`console.dir(f)` results in -

```
Fruit
  color: "red"
  __proto__:
    constructor: class Fruit
    __proto__: Object
```

When a new object is constructed from this class, `Fruit.prototype` becomes `f.__proto__`. So `Fruit.prototype === f.__proto__` is `true`.

So you can access the static properties by `f.__proto__.constructor.count`. Since properties on `__proto__` are inherited to the instance directly, you can access them by `f.constructor.count`.